# My C# code on Visual Studio 2013 doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to be an educated lazy chemistry student, by making a C# program that can do chemistry calculation for me. In order to make the code, I have to understand well the procedures in chemistry class.

I am new to any kind of programming, C# is my first language.
The code works fine for 1 Element calculation, but not 2 Elements calculation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MassCalculation myMassCalculation = new MassCalculation();
            TwoMassCalculation myTwoMassCalculation = new TwoMassCalculation();


            Console.WriteLine("How many elements are in the compound?");
            string userMainInput = Console.ReadLine();


            if (userMainInput == "1")
            {
                myMassCalculation.Amount1 = 1;

                Console.WriteLine("What is the ELEMENT?");

                string userInput1 = Console.ReadLine();

                Elements element;

                if (Enum.TryParse<Elements>(userInput1, true, out element))
                {
                    switch (element)
                    {
                        case Elements.Na:
                            myMassCalculation.Element1 = 22.990;
                            break;
                        case Elements.Cl:
                            myMassCalculation.Element1 = 35.453;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("How many?");

                string userAmount1 = Console.ReadLine();
                int myAmount1 = int.Parse(userAmount1);
                myMassCalculation.Amount1 = myAmount1;

                myMassCalculation.DoCalculation();

                resultOfMassCalculation(myMassCalculation);
            }

            if (userMainInput == "2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What is the First ELEMENT?");

                string userInput1 = Console.ReadLine();

                Elements element;

                if (Enum.TryParse<Elements>(userInput1, true, out element))
                {
                    switch (element)
                    {
                        case Elements.Na:
                            myMassCalculation.Element1 = 22.990;
                            break;
                        case Elements.Cl:
                            myMassCalculation.Element1 = 35.453;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }   
                }

                Console.WriteLine("How many?");

                string userAmount1 = Console.ReadLine();
                int myAmount1 = int.Parse(userAmount1);
                myMassCalculation.Amount1 = myAmount1;


                Console.WriteLine("What is the Second ELEMENT?");

                string userInput2 = Console.ReadLine();

                if (Enum.TryParse<Elements>(userInput2, true, out element))
                {
                    switch (element)
                    {
                        case Elements.Na:
                            myTwoMassCalculation.Element2 = 22.990;
                            break;
                        case Elements.Cl:
                            myTwoMassCalculation.Element2 = 35.453;
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("How many?");

                string userAmount2 = Console.ReadLine();
                int myAmount2 = int.Parse(userAmount2);
                myTwoMassCalculation.Amount2 = myAmount2;

                myTwoMassCalculation.DoCalculation();

                resultOfMassCalculation(myTwoMassCalculation);
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private static void resultOfMassCalculation(MassCalculation calculation)
        {
            Console.Write("The Mass is {0}g/mol", calculation.DoCalculation());
        }
    }
    enum Elements
    {
        Na,
        Cl,
    }



    class MassCalculation
    {
        public double Element1 { get; set; }
        public int Amount1 { get; set; }

        public virtual double DoCalculation()
        {
            double result = Element1 * Amount1;
            return result;
        }
    }
    class TwoMassCalculation : MassCalculation
    {
        public double Element2 { get; set; }
        public int Amount2 { get; set; }

        public override double DoCalculation()
        {
            double result = Element1 * Amount1 + Element2 * Amount2;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help! I know it seems somewhat unprofessional. I have just started programming a week ago, and this is the best I can do. I need guidance.

The only elements defined in the code is Na and Cl, I am trying to calculate NaCl. When everything is in place, I will add more elements to the list, and many more different types of calculations.

I'll take constructive opinions.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: do you get a error or is just the excpected result not ok?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Doesn't work properly'?

Comment: It works, but everytime I try to calculate 2 elements compound, such as NaCl, the code ignores the 1st element, and only takes 2nd element into calculation, which is very off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem in the code when elements are two. You are assigning the first element value to "myMassCalculation' object and second element value to "myTwoMassCalculation". When you call "DoCalculation()" "myTwoMassCalculation.Element1' and "myTwoMassCalculation.Amount1" have no values. That's why it is giving wrong answer. Make the following changes and try:

```
            if (Enum.TryParse<Elements>(userInput1, true, out element))
            {
                switch (element)
                {
                    case Elements.Na:
                        myTwoMassCalculation.Element1 = 22.990;
                        break;
                    case Elements.Cl:
                        myTwoMassCalculation.Element1 = 35.453;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }   
            }

            Console.WriteLine("How many?");

            string userAmount1 = Console.ReadLine();
            int myAmount1 = int.Parse(userAmount1);
            myTwoMassCalculation.Amount1 = myAmount1;
```

Comment: I tried to make the class "TwoMassCalculation" derive from "MassCalculation", which I assume the class "TwoMassCalculation" would inherit every characteristics of "MassCalculation". You can see my point in line 141 : class TwoMassCalculation : MassCalculation. You can say that I am trying to avoid "Copy Paste." Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I refactored your code a little. It will work the same way, but wont crash on inappropriate user input

https://dotnetfiddle.net/CMQugr

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, double> Elements = new Dictionary<string, double>
        {
            {"Na",22.990},
            {"Cl",35.453}
        };

        public static void Main()
        {
            double result = 0;

            int elemenCountInput;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("How many elements are in the compound?");
            } while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out elemenCountInput));

            for (int i = 0; i < elemenCountInput; i++)
            {
                string element;
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What is the {0} element", (i + 1));
                    element = Console.ReadLine();
                } while (!Elements.ContainsKey(element));

                int amount;
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("How many");
                } while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out amount));

                result += Elements[element] * amount;
            }

            Console.Write("The Mass is {0}g/mol", result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code blown my mind away. I will take your code as a learning example when I learn enough to understand it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Though I appreciate the effort you made to create a perfect working code, I am still looking for the reasons why my code doesn't work the way I want it to work. I would like to take baby steps and walk my way up the top.

Comment: @EricDuong another guys have already posted answers why it is not working. I didn't want to post duplicate. Happy learning!

Comment: @Szer Nice one.  I just came back from my meeting to write almost exactly this.  You saved me the time :)  +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

1. Create a class for elements (name (string), whatever that number is (double/decimal)
2. Create a static dictionary of them of them indexed by name.
3. Loop through the parameters to Main (or loop around an input command) looking up each entry in the dictionary then perform the calculation.
4. Convert to LINQ if desired.

This is be a great approach and should teach you a lot.  I'm not going to write it for you (time and desire), but I may come back later with an example.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. Your ideas can be a great improvement for my coding skill. Currently I am not at the level of manipulating arrays, collections, dictionaries, and LINQ. I will take note of these suggestions and put my mind into active thinking.